# Infinite binomial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

Let
$\displaystyle\pi_{lr}\left(p\right) :=
{l \choose r}p^{r}\left(1 - p\right)^{l - r}\quad$ ( i.e., the binomial probability with parameters $\displaystyle l$ and $\displaystyle r$ ).

I'm interested in computing the following sum:
$
\displaystyle\sum_{l = r}^{\infty}\pi_{lr}\left(p\right)
$

I've two questions:

1. Does this summation converge to a simple function of $\displaystyle p$ and $\displaystyle r$ ?.
2. If I were to settle on approximating it with $\displaystyle\sum_{l = r}^{N}\pi_{lr}(p)$ for some $\displaystyle N$. How large should I choose $\displaystyle N$ ( as a function of $\displaystyle p$ and $\displaystyle r$ ) ?.

Comment: Could you clarify the second part of the second question ?

Comment: sure, if the summation didn't admit a clean expression (such as $1/p$), I was planning to study it computationally. In which case, the obvious thing to do is to try to approximate the infinite sum with a finite one. However, one needs to choose a large enough $N$ so that this approximation is a good one. My second question was how to choose $N$. But it is now irrelevant, given the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! It was just not clear to me; now, I understand. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\pi_{\ell r}\pars{p} \equiv
> {\ell \choose r}p^{r}\pars{1 - p}^{\ell - r}.\qquad
> \sum_{\ell = r}^{\infty}\pi_{\ell r}\pars{p}:\ {\LARGE ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{\ell = r}^{\infty}\pi_{\ell r}\pars{p}} =
\sum_{\ell = r}^{\infty}{\ell \choose r}p^{r}\pars{1 - p}^{\ell - r} =
p^{r}\sum_{\ell = r}^{\infty}\overbrace{\ell \choose \ell - r}
^{\ds{=\ {\ell \choose r}}}\ \pars{1 - p}^{\ell - r}
\\[5mm] = &\
p^{r}\sum_{\ell = r}^{\infty}
\overbrace{{-r - 1 \choose \ell - r}\pars{-1}^{\ell - r}}
^{\ds{=\ {\ell \choose \ell - r}}}\
\pars{1 - p}^{\ell - r}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\ell\ -\ r\ \mapsto\ \ell}{=}\,\,\,&
p^{r}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
{-r - 1 \choose \ell}\pars{-1}^{\ell}\pars{1 - p}^{\ell}
\\[5mm] = &\
p^{r}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{-r - 1 \choose \ell}\pars{p - 1}^{\ell} =
p^{r}\,\bracks{1 + \pars{p - 1}}^{-r - 1} = \bbx{1 \over p}
\end{align}

Comment: very nice, thank you!

Comment: @Ozzy You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As far as approximations goes, we have $$
\sum_{l=r}^\infty{l\choose r}p^r(1-p)^{l-r}=\left({p\over 1-p}\right)^r\sum_{l=r}^\infty{l\choose r}(1-p)^l
$$
Write $a_l = {l\choose r}(1-p)^l.$  Then $${a_{l+1}\over a_l} = {l+1\over l+1-r}(1-p)\to 1-p$$ so that we essentially have a geometric series.  Observing that ${l+1\over l+1-r}$ decreases to $1$ as $l\to\infty$ makes it easy to bound the omitted terms.

As to the first part of the question, I don't know, but I doubt it, except perhaps when $r$ is very small.  Since the ratio of successive terms is a rational function of $l$ for fixed $p$ and $r$, this is a [hypergeometric series.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricSeries.html) There is a large theory of these, which I unfortunately know nothing about.  I've added the hypergeometric-function tag in hopes of attracting someone knowledgeable.

Comment: thank you for your thoughtful answer and also adding the additional tag!